# How do I send parameters through postman, for a moodle webservice?

Tags: json, postman, moodle

Consuming moodle web services is an art in itself. For this question I have already set up the service to be available, I've created a user, with the correct user rights, and I have a token that works. My issue is that I am unable to send parameters correctly, so the execution of the web service fails on parameter validation.

I am trying to create a new user through the existing webservice, named `core_user_create_users`. This requires an array called users, which I am trying to provide in JSON format.

However, I am simply not able to do it.

The tutorials I've seen, puts the token, and function name in the URL directly. I've also added a XDEBUG_SESSION_START so I can debug in phpstorm

```
http://myserver.example.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=[mytoken]
&wsfunction=core_user_create_users&XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM
```

Then I've tried to include the json containing an array of `users` in two different ways:

In form-data, passing a parameter called `users`, containing a json array of one single user. This parameter appears in the debugger, but still as a string, and not an array. However, I discovered that the Content-type was defaulted to `multipart/form-data; boundary=<calculated when request is sent>`. I changed it to `application/json`, but now the parameter does not even appear in the code, when I run debugger step by step. The parameter `users` is no more.

Then I tried to include it as a json structure, selecting 'raw' data to be sent. Now it does not matter which content type I set, the parameter does not appear anyway.

How am I actually supposed to send the data so that moodle will get it as an array? I've spoken to several people who says that the moodle web services does accept json as default format for their webservices, so I'm thinking I must be doing something wrong i postman...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Postman **Params** tab and set the required params in the table :

- `wstoken` : your Webservice token generated inside Moodle Administration panel
- `wsfunction` : the name of the function of the webservice you are calling - here core_user_create_users
- `moodlewsrestformat` : set to `json`
- the other params if you have function parameters

In the **Headers** tab, you can set a key for `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It should work.

[image]

You should turn on the debugging messages set to "developer" in Moodle Administration panel in order to have useful infos about possible issues in your functions or parameters.

Comment: I've tested your solution extensively. The Token ends up with a null value in moodle if I try to put it in the params tab. If it is in the body, the authentication works. My users array ends up as a string in moodle no matter what I do, and I am back to square 1.

Comment: Still does not work unfortunately. I found that the moodlewsrestformat : set to json part has nothing to do with what moodle expects from me. It states what moodle returns.

I did find one solution, where I made all of the object parameters singular in postman. writing an array with object properties like `array[i]property = 'value'` for every single value in the data structure, so I have moved on. But I never really found a way to send actual json...